# No windows executable is generated when building tinyMediaManager

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a Windows distribution of [tinyMediaManager](https://gitlab.com/tinyMediaManager/tinyMediaManager). Its Gitlab instructions says:

> Building from source tinyMediaManager is compiled using Apache's build
> automation tool, Maven. Check that you have it installed (and git, of
> course) before attempting a build.
>
> **Clone this repository to your computer git clone**
> https://gitlab.com/tinyMediaManager/tinyMediaManager.git
>
> **Build using:**
> maven mvn package
>
> After that you will find the packaged build in the folder **dist**

However, when I build using the command "mvn package" I get a folder called **target** with some other files, including some .jar files, instead of a "dist" folder with .exe for windows. When I executed them, nothing happens.

[image: Screenshot of Directory]

This is my first time compiling source from java into a Windows executable.

Why is the "dist" folder with a Windows executable not created?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is indeed not correct, *mvn package* does not generate the *dist* folder.

There is a [profile called dist](https://gitlab.com/tinyMediaManager/tinyMediaManager/-/blob/devel/pom.xml#L622) that you need to build with in order for the folder to be generated:

> mvn package -Pdist

The above command will generate the dist folder, including a zip file with the Windows executable.

I guess the build behaviour changed along the way, and that they missed to update the readme.